# Classic ASP Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 error '80040e14' Login failed for user, but not the one I specified

Tags: sql, vbscript, asp-classic

Getting a very odd error that I can't seem to track down.  Running Classic ASP on IIS10.  I'm specifying a user in my connection string, but the application seems to be "defaulting" to another user.  I can't figure out where this user is being specified.

```
set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
connectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=serverxy;Initial Catalog=hazard;USER Id=xxxxx;PASSWORD=yyyyy;"
conn.Open connectionString
...do sql queries, etc...
```

This happens on both my production server, development server and my development desktop machine.

Comment: `Provider=SQLNCLI11` indicates SQLServer. Can you check your assumption with SQLProfiler? Start application and look for unsuccessful logon attempts?

Comment: Ingaz, that helped tremendously.  This error was very odd.  Hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: Upon further reflection, the "odd error" was actually from a linked server.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Profiler helped me figure out how to fix the problem. It showed that the user I was specifying was actually working.  There was a view calling a query on another server.  The database on this server was actually offline and had been moved.  I updated the view to use the new server and all worked after.  Completely forgot about Profiler as it's been ages since I've had to use it.